# cors with htaccess and jquery

Tags: jquery, .htaccess, cors

In my apache modHeader is enabled. First off: my apache has not a fully qualified domain name. Is that perhaps the reason for my problem?

I want to deliver json files with CORS.

In http://78.47.45.6/one/sites/default/files/bla1/13/kontakt.json you can see the very important data ;)

In the same folder http://78.47.45.6/one/sites/default/files/bla1/13/ there is a .htaccess file with the following content:

> Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

That's all because there exists other htaccess files in the root.

The page pano-maen.rhcloud.com/willkommen.html from another server has the following js:

```
// Using jQuery
$.ajax({
/*   xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
},*/
type: "GET",
url: "http://78.47.45.6/one/sites/default/files/bla1/13/kontakt.json"
}).done(function (data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

With the xhrFields commented out I get the result in Firefox. But chrome doesn't accept this.
With activated xhrFields neither FF nor chrome gives a result! I tested the htaccess in multiple directories. How do I get the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ... is therefore not allowed access.

to vanish??

THX in advance

maen

Comment: http://enable-cors.org

Comment: I tested this code on Firefox Dev Edition and Chrome, and it gets the result...

Answer (score 0):

From [this site](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html)

You can add `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` to your `.htaccess`, however this will only work if your ISP has `mod_headers` loaded

If I remember well you have to modify this in the .htaccess on the server where that serves your javascript (rhcloud.com ...)

As alternative you might find some information how you maybe could use `jsonp` to circumvent the same origin policy

Edit:
You might need to have a look if you also need these headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
Access-Control-Max-Age
```

Comment: THX, but as I wrote: the .htaccess exists in the same folder, modHeader is enabled and .htaccess (owner: www-data, group: www-data) has the content Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*".

Comment: I edited my post. The access control allow origin must be on the server that is serving your webpage and javascript